# Apache Flink and Lucene in-memory index

Tags: lucene, apache-flink

Currently I'm trying to implement my first job for Flink engine and here is the thing:
In a nut shell the task is quite simple - I have 2 data streams (both are unbounded) and I need to join them by a list of parameters.
One dataset is suppose to be a big one (around 1m records) and another one is relatively small (~1k, records will arrive and then removed by ttl).
So I've decided to use keyed state for big dataset and broadcast state for small one.

The question here - can I use Lucene(pure in memory structure, no persistence) to match records , is it ok to have such state ? (I don't want to write custom serialiser for Lucene and will re-create it when job starts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, depending on the rules for "join them by a list of parameters", and how big the parameter list can be, there might be a way to do this still using keyed state.

Second, since the small data set is going to be broadcast, I think you'll need to implement your own TTL, versus trying to leverage Flink's support.

Third, your idea of using Lucene could work. You'd want to save the small data set in state (e.g. map state, where key is the TTL time, and value is a list of your incoming records that expire on that time), and then build (or recreate) the transient Lucene index.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like to use Lucene in order to be able to more efficiently find the matches (compared to being limited to what is offered by Flink's built-in managed state types). A couple of thoughts:

1. It's not clear how you would make this fault tolerant and rescalable.
2. 1m records is still pretty small. Why not try a straightforward implementation with the Table API first? In most cases I'd expect that to be good enough.

Comment: yeah, an idea is to speed up matching process , I've already tried to implement it in a straight-forward way without any index (using `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction`) and its quite slow when trying to match all keys in `processBroadcastElement`, which is not surprising because its 1m * 1k operations